How to minimize the time spent creating UX deliverables?
As a UX freelancer I've found that creating deliverables documenting the research and design process often takes longer than I feel it should.
I was wondering if there are any tips on how to be more efficient in putting the information into deliverables (i.e. competitive analysis, value proposition, personas, empathy maps, etc.) and how to keep the design of the deliverables consistent?
secondly, how much time is expected to put into the design of a deliverable (once you have all the information ready to go) and is there a tool that can make this process smoother or easier?
Thanks in advance!

If you can provide more specific examples of where you have found it challenging to timebox certain activities, it might help with getting a more useful answer. As the question currently stands, I think you just have to find ways to do things more efficiently by having a solid process and use simple but flexible templates.

I believe that you should be spending just as much time analyzing and synthesizing the results as you should be spending on the actual collecting of data (if not more). How efficiently you can come up with the research results and insights depends on how well the research is planned. A big part of cutting down the time required to produce deliverables is to remove the unnecessary aspects (like making the presentation look nice, beyond clarity and legibility). If you have enough experience doing research, you'll establish processes and templates that reduce the time spent on producing the deliverables. I am not sure that you can cut down time on all the planning, analysis and reporting of the results.
As for your second question, it really depends on the type of research that you are doing, and I think you have to be guided by the data and results that you are presenting, so there's no specific answer to this question. Suffice to say that if you plan and structure the research well, you will be saving yourself a lot of time already no matter what. I'd budget as much time in the planning as you do for the analysis and presentation of the results. The actual amount of time required to conduct the research varies a lot more than the other parts (because it depends on how much raw data you need).
